# How to restore selected path in FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#-4.0

In my application i just want to restore the path which was selected previously..

```
using (FolderBrowserDialog dlgDirestorySelector = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
string directoryName;
dlgDirestorySelector.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
if (dlgDirestorySelector.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
  directoryName = dlgDirestorySelector.SelectedPath;
}
//Processing code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the [RootFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.rootfolder.aspx) property before you show the dialog.

Alternatively if the folder path is custom (and not a special folder), you simply need to set the `SelectedPath` property before showing the dialog (there are some rules around the path being set, explained in the "Remarks" section of the documentation I linked).